# How to calculate bits needed for host, bits left for network, number of available networks?

Tags: subnet, network, ip-address, networking

I have a class b address of 145.14.0.0

I need to create a scheme where each subnet accommodates 2259 hosts.

can someone explain step by step how to do that

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (before the Internet went commercial in 1993) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) to the question linked above explains it all. In any case, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. We get many, many questions about IPv4 addressing and subnetting, but they are all covered in the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: The step-by-step explanation is in the two-part answer to which I linked.